# WCF 3.5, AsyncBridge. Wrap in async-await

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

At work I'm currently stuck in 3.5, but we are using the asyncbridge for async-await. We're using alot of old WCF async calls, and I want to wrap this into the new async-await pattern.

I'm wrapping this as follows:

```
    // async is wrong
    public /*async*/ Task<ScannedDocumentResult> GetScannedDocumentsTask(String assignmentId)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<ScannedDocumentResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ScannedDocumentResult>();
        EventHandler<GetScannedDocumentsCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.UserState != tcs)
                    return;

                if (e.Error != null)
                    tcs.SetException(e.Error);
                else if (e.Cancelled)
                    tcs.SetCanceled();
                else
                    tcs.SetResult(e.Result);

                GetScannedDocumentsCompleted -= handler;
            };
        GetScannedDocumentsCompleted += handler;
        GetScannedDocumentsAsync(assignmentId, tcs);

        return tcs.Task;            
    }
```

The following are genereted in the 3.5 WCF proxy:

GetScannedDocumentsAsync
GetScannedDocumentsCompleted
GetScannedDocumentsEventArgs

Something tells me that this can be done alot cleaner, have I missed something cruical?

Also, will this method execute async at all? Compiling with the async operator just generates an error.

Comment: Does `GetScannedDocumentsAsync` return `IAsyncResult`? If so, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/06/27/10179452.aspx) excellent blog post describes how to do it right.

Comment: `async` is only allowed on methods that have `await` inside them. What is the definition of `GetScannedDocumentsAsync`?

Comment: If you think `async` is required for a method to actually execute asynchronously, then you don't actually understand what `async` means. You should probably read more about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also be getting a `BeginGetScannedDocuments` and `EndGetScannedDocuments`, which you can wrap using `TaskFactory.FromAsync`. I have a blog post that shows [how to use task wrappers with old-school (pre-4.5) WCF](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html) (both on the server and client).

Comment: With some help from Skeet I figured this out in another thread, which simplified things a lot + allowed me to use as many parameters as I want. Marked you as an answer as well though :)